# Create NUnit test with resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, resharper

I installed Resharper 5 with visual studio 2010 Team system with NUnit. It finds NUnit and shows 2 types of tests in the options: MSTest and NUnit.

I can create a MSTest by right clicking the function. How do I accomplish this same thing but for NUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way to do this automatically.